# VS2010 DSL samples

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dsl

I want to create my own DSL but working with DSL Definition is confusing.
Where can I find some samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk) is a good jumping-off point for VS2010 DSL samples and related items.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen this and I've found just this one! Is there any resource to show me a simple sample which present step by step implementation?